# Mi php no conecta con mysql en hosting godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, godaddy

Hola tengo una duda muy fuerte, por alguna razón cuando intento conectar mi php con mi db de mysql es como si estuviera haciendo mal la conexión, lo he subido en otros servidores tal cual y me funciona correctamente.
no sé si en godaddy tengo que hacer algo especial primera vez que uso ese servicio

```
<?php

function conectar()
{
    $user = "crea***"; //usuario de sql
    $pass = "d2lq***"; //password de sql
    $host = '107.***'; //nombre del host
    $dbname = 'crea***'; //nombre de la baso de datos

    try {
        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

        return $con;
    }
    catch ( \Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}


conectar();

function desconectar($conex)
{
    $conex = null;
}

?>
```

Actualizo?

primero hice varios experimentos probé hasta una estructura PDO y ahí si me arrojo mensajes de error y me di cuenta que el problema no es la conexión porque en realidad si está conectando correctamente, ahora lo que sucede es que a la hora de extraer o ingresar datos de la base de datos me aparece este error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/mokuj1rqpqan/public_html/registro.php:44 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/mokuj1rqpqan/public_html/registro.php on line 44
```

confirmo que si funciona la db porque aparece el primer dato que ingreso en la db pero en vez de continuar al la siguiente pagina sucede esto

Comment: Quiza este link te resulte util https://www.godaddy.com/es/help/conectar-con-bases-de-datos-de-forma-remota-en-panel-de-control-de-alojamiento-16103. Saludos

Comment: Antes que nada te recomiendo quitar los datos que usas para tu conexión, por seguridad. Después, qué output obtienes al intentar la conexión?

Comment: Tengo un servicio en GoDaddy y uso `localhost` para el servidor (host), ¿lo intentaste?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. Migré una base de datos y archivos desde un servidor a godaddy pero no logro que funcione. Ni siquiera usando el ejemplo de conexion de godaddy: https://www.godaddy.com/es/help/conexion-a-mysql-usando-php-216 Alguna idea? Qué has cambiado en el cpanel de las opciones de php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba la conexión y consulta de este modo:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}


/* Consulta alguna tabla que haya en tu DB */
if ($query = $mysqli->query("SELECT field FROM table LIMIT 1")) {
    printf("La selección devolvió %d filas.\n", $query->num_rows);
    $resultado->close();
}
```

FYI: Lo anterior lo he tomado de la misma documentación.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda.. despues de intentar esto anoche y consultarlo con la almohada llegue por fin a la causa del problema, tenia que editar las extensiones y las opciones de la version del php en el cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Emil,

1. que error te muestra?
2. Tienes un catch `echo $e->getMessage()`, que es lo que te muestra?
3. Has un `var_dump($con);`

GoDaddy no debe tener restricciones si la conexion que intentas hacer esta dentro del servidor de su hosting, pero si quieres hacer una conexion de tu entorno local puede que tengas que configurar los permisos `%%%%` o `0000` en tu mysql de GoDaddy.
Pero para dar un diagnostico necesito saber si te muestra algun error.

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta :(